# Action Controller params not refreshing on multiple update requests from Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm writing specs for controller, two update requests under one case

```
 it "can update or delete user phones" do
   json = {:id => 1, :format => :json, :name => "sample1"}
   put :update, params: json
   
   json = {:id => 1, :format => :json, :name => "sample2"}
   put :update, params: json
 end
```

In debugger at update action, it shows the params from first request when second update statement hits controller.  The params are not getting refreshed, this was a rails 4.2 application which is being upgraded. Can someone point on the syntax changes with rspec and rails which is breaking this test case. Thanks

rspec - 3.6
Rails - 5.1
Ruby - 2.5.7

Comment: what was the solution? i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be sent resource paremeters as singular name block

Etc: Resource post

And parameters: `{ id: 1, post: { name: "sample 1"}, format: :json }`

Also, must be `put your_update_path`

Comment: update is the action name and it will take the controller path since it's per controller level defined, I didn't understood your response